# PHP Session Variables

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-variables, html-content-extraction

A user will click on a link which will open a new page (code below).  My problem is that when this new page is opened, it creates a NEW session ID.  How do I stop this from happening?

```
require_once('../../config.php');    //Database connection details
require_once('../../connect.php');   //Connect to database

session_start();  <----------- HERE


if(isset($_GET['id'])) 
{

$id = $_GET['id'];
$tbl_uploads = $_SESSION['COMPANY_ID'].'_uploads';

$query = "SELECT username, type, size, content FROM $tbl_uploads WHERE id = '$id'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
list($username, $type, $size, $content) = mysql_fetch_array($result);

header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$username");
echo $content;

mysql_close($link);
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Any of the required files actually send any output. If so, session_start() should go before them.

Comment: You need to declare the if statement better! I would suggest using a question mark after the first sentance. ;)

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have on the first line of the file
`error_reporting(E_ALL);`

I think you are having some other bug here, the session_start() should not affect this.

Comment: I added that in, and no reportable errors.  The page remains blank!

Answer (score 0):

Is `$_GET['id']` actually set? Slap an `else` clause on that initial `if` and spit out an error of some sort if it's not. Perhaps something's turning your click into a POST.

Comment: It is, I've checked that.  If I remove the session_start(); and change the code to type in a specific table name in place of $tbl_uploads, it works!  I've tried putting a session_write_close(); function in there before the headers, but that doesn't help either!

Comment: Is this script running on a different domain (sub-domain) from the one where the original link is? Or on a different path? Perhaps your session cookie's host identifier is too restrictive and this script doesn't fall under the "real" session's bounds, so you get a new session.

Answer (score 0):

session_start() might be the problem. When you start a session it should make a session ID. That is the way it seems to me anyway. Could you include the code for session_start()?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this:

```
$sid = session_id();
if ($sid == ""){ 
       //Session should be created
       session_start();
}//else Session already exists
```